# Unable to parse data larger than 305kB sent from web service to J2ME device

Tags: java-me, sax

I am having a big problem where the following error is thrown when my application receives a SOAP message larger than 305kb, from a WCF web service.

> java.rmi.MarshalException: SAXParseException in the return SOAP message from the server.

I have done a lot of testing to identify that this error only occurs when the return SOAP message is larger than 305kb (roughly around 320,000 characters).

Is there such a limitation? and if so, is there a method to increase the number of characters or size that can be supported?

Any suggestions / insight will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

assuming its because you run out of memory because of building up a DOM model for the response... it would be good to check that...I would just make a plain vanilla http request to the remote service. forget all the soap libraries. then use a pull parser to read the response. you then can parse as you stream the response back meaning low footprint.